# How can I use a repeat control with multiple data sources, sorted by date in an XPages application?

Tags: xpages

XPages Repeat Control with multiple data sources sorted by date

I want to create a repeat control with multiple data sources. In the snippet is only one view as source but I've multiple views in different databases and I want to show them all in this repeat control, sorted by date.

All views have three columns. 1. Datum (date to sort the entries by date), 2. DatumText and 3. InfoTitel (to show as text in the repeat control).

Is it possible to do this?

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{view1}"
var="rowData" rows="15" styleClass="ul_liste">
<xp:link escape="true" id="link1"
target="_blank"
value="#{javascript:rowData.getDocument().getHttpURL()}"
styleClass="a">
<xp:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("InfoTitel")}]]></xp:this.title>
<xp:this.text><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowData.getColumnValue("DatumText") + " " + rowData.getColumnValue("InfoTitel")}]]></xp:this.text>
</xp:link>
<xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Get all the entries in each database using ssjs or java. Loop them and store the unid, date, title and dbpath in a list<model>. sort the list using a comparable and return the list to the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Create two java files Data and Runner

```
package com.so;

import java.util.Date;

import lotus.domino.DateTime;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;

public class Data{

    private String dbpath;
    private Date created;
    private String title;
    private String unid;

    
    public Data(){
        
    }
    
    public String getDbpath() {
        return dbpath;
    }

    public void setDbpath(String DbPath) {
        this.dbpath = DbPath;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(DateTime Created) throws NotesException {
        this.created = Created.toJavaDate();
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.title = Title;
    }

    public String getUnid() {
        return unid;
    }

    public void setUnid(String Unid) {
        this.unid = Unid;
    }
}






package com.so;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.swing.text.View;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

import lotus.domino.*;

public class Runner implements Serializable {
    
    private transient Database db;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Data> datalist = new ArrayList<Data>();
    
    public Runner() throws NotesException{
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Data> GetData() throws NotesException{
        
        if(datalist.isEmpty()){
            GetDbData("srv1/acme","names.nsf", "People", "FirstName");
            GetDbData("srv2/acme","catalog.nsf", "ByServer", "Title");
            
            // sort the data
            ArrayList<Data> dlist = sortByCreatedDesc();
            return dlist;
        }else{
            return sortByCreatedDesc();
        }
        
    }
    public void GetDbData(String srv, String dbpath, String view, String titleFld) throws NotesException{
        
        try{
        Session session = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
        db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        
        Database dbx = session.getDatabase(srv,dbpath);
        lotus.domino.View vv = dbx.getView(view);
        ViewEntryCollection vec = vv.getAllEntries();
        ViewEntry entry = vec.getFirstEntry();
        while(entry!=null){
            
            Data data = new Data();
            Document d = entry.getDocument();
            
            data.setCreated(d.getCreated());
            data.setDbpath(dbx.getFilePath());
            data.setTitle(d.getItemValueString(titleFld));
            data.setUnid(d.getUniversalID());
            datalist.add(data);
            
            ViewEntry temp = entry;
            entry = vec.getNextEntry(entry);
            temp.recycle();
       }
        }catch(Exception e){
            
        }
    }

    // return a a list of unids for use in repeat 
    public List<String> sortByCreatedUnid() throws NotesException {
        return datalist.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Data::getCreated).reversed()).map(Data::getUnid).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    // return a list of data asc
    public ArrayList<Data> sortByCreated() throws NotesException {
        return (ArrayList<Data>) datalist.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Data::getCreated)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    // return a list of data desc
    public ArrayList<Data> sortByCreatedDesc() throws NotesException {
        return (ArrayList<Data>) datalist.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Data::getCreated).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Add your bean

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Runner</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.so.Runner</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

Create your xpage

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" value="#{javascript:Runner.GetData()}" rows="30"
        var="coll">
        <xp:panel tagName="div" id="pane" style="" styleClass="">
        <xp:text value="#{coll.unid}" escape="true" id="computedField4" tagName="span" style="" styleClass=""></xp:text>
        <xp:text value="#{coll.created}" escape="true" id="computedField1" tagName="span" style="" styleClass=""></xp:text>
    </xp:panel> 
    </xp:repeat>
    
</xp:view>
```

The list returned to the repeat is sorted descending.
you can add more values to the model or get the values from the document in the repeat by using a data source and connect it to coll.unid but then you also need to set the db in the data source

the datalist is stored in sessionScope so if you reload the page it is fetched from cache.

If you want to get the title value from a column instead of field you need to change that in the GetDbData method

Comment: Thanks a lot. After saving I changed the Runner to GetDbData("","names.nsf", "People", "FirstName") mean same server. No errors but if I open the XPage in Browser nothing happens.

Comment: are you not getting an errormessage and no errors in DDE?
can you check the error and trace log on server and see if anything is there.